# How to solve AmbiguousColumn error in postgresql with ruby project

Tags: ruby, postgresql, join, sequel

I would like to join two query result.
First one is

```
Gig.where(id:gigsInRadioIDS)
When I convert result to json I get this result
[{"id":1,"address":"test1"},{"id":2,"address":"test2"}
```

Second is.

```
Slot.where(status:"available").where(Sequel.lit('("from" > ?) AND ("to" < ?)', fromdate, todate))
when I convert result to json I get this result
[{"id":15,"status":"available","gig_id":1}]
```

What I want is to inner join to result
so I hope to get this result(I abbreviated some non related snippet)

```
[{"id":15,"status":"available","gig_id":1,"id":1,"address":"test1"}]
```

What I have tried is

```
Gig.where(id:gigsInRadioIDS).as(:tb_gig).join(Slot.where(status:"available").where(Sequel.lit('("from" > ?) AND ("to" < ?)', fromdate, todate)), gig_id: :id)
```

And I got this error

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...) AS "t1" ON ("t1"."gig_id" = "gigs"."id") WHERE ("id" IN (2...
```

Thanks for reading this complex code.
Any news will be big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to approach it. It looks like you are querying Slots with some Gigs data mixed in, so you may want to start with your Slot model. The regular join syntax is a little easier to understand and makes it easier to select columns from both tables (i.e. instead of `WHERE fk IN (..)`). As a bonus, you can mix your gig_id filter into the `JOIN` clause. Finally, you don't need to use Sequel.lit to do greater than / less than in your `WHERE` clause, and you should be explicit about the columns you want to select.

Here's how I would write it:

```
Slot.join(:gigs, [[:id, :gig_id], [:id, gigsInRadioIDS]])
  .where(status: 'available') { (from() > fromdate) & (to() < todate) }
  .select(Sequel[:slots][:id].as(:slot_id), :status, :gig_id, :address)
```

Getting `.all` of the records and outputting JSON should yield something like:

```
[{"slot_id":15,"status":"available","gig_id":1,"address":"test1"}]
```

Note the `Sequel[:table_name][:column_name]` syntax. This is the new style of fully-qualifying identifiers in Sequel 4.49+. (In past versions of Sequel, it would have been written like `:table_name__column_name`, but that syntax is now deprecated.)

Comment: Great. It works well. Thanks very much.
I can't find such query syntac, would you give me reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `where(id:gigsInRadioIDS)` translates into `WHERE ("id" IN (...))`, and since both gigs and slots have an "id" column, the database doesn't know which id you want.

You need to explicitly specify the table with `where{{gigs[:id] => gigsInRadioIDS}}`

[Querying with Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/querying.rdoc#from)

Comment: Thanks but I got this error,
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer: